# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception, outofrangeexception

I have the following List:

```
public Question init()
{
     questions = new List<GameManager.Question>();
     questions.Add(new GameManager.Question("Ya no hay técnicas que te puedan salvar.", "Sí que las hay, sólo que nunca las has aprendido."));
     questions.Add(new GameManager.Question("Espero que tengas un barco para una rápida huida.", "¿Por qué? ¿Acaso querías pedir uno prestado?"));
     questions.Add(new GameManager.Question("Ahora entiendo lo que significan basura y estupidez.", "Me alegra que asistieras a tu reunión familiar diaria."));

     return questions;
}
```

I initialize the following buttons on start:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questionList.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject child = Instantiate(questionButton, buttonLayout.transform);
    child.GetComponent<Text>().text = questionList[i].answer;
    child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(i));
}
```

And I have the following code:

```
public void QuestionCheck(int index)
{
    if (currentQuestion.answer == questionList[index].answer)
    {
        playerAsk = 1;
        playerScore += 1;
        scorePlayer.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Jugador: " + playerScore;
        roundStatus.text = "Has ganado la ronda!";
        roundStatus.color = Color.green;
        correct.Play();
    }
}
```

I think it crashes on the following line:

```
if (currentQuestion.answer == questionList[index].answer)
```

Also if I try the following line it also crashes:

```
questionList.RemoveAt(index);
```

I obtain the following error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index

Why this is happening?

EDIT: I've seen that the index from QuestionCheck is always 15, why this is happening?

Comment: run a loop and see whats inside the `questionList`

Comment: I think you should use `questions[index]` instead

Comment: @AndrewE inside the list everything is ok.

Comment: also, why not use a dictionary? key can be the question, value can be the answer, and since no two questions should be the same, i think that would be better

Comment: Its the index variable from QuestionCheck, it's always 15 but I don't know why (list goes from 0 to 14).

Comment: Where do you call the QuestionCheck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is scoping issue. Once the event happens, `i` is already at `questionList.Count` which is out of the array range. And all of your `QuestionCheck` will be called with `questionList.Count` (15 in your case)

What you want to do is save `i` to a temporary value, and used that instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questionList.Count; i++)
{
    var currentIndex = i;
    GameObject child = Instantiate(questionButton, buttonLayout.transform);
    child.GetComponent<Text>().text = questionList[i].answer;
    child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(currentIndex ));
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! But I don't undestand why they all point to `i` instead of value. Isn't int a primitive type?

Comment: @Lechucico See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1663383). Its a JavaScript question, but the underlying effects and reasons are the same.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your onClick listener is not evaluated within the loop but afterwards when the button is clicked.

```
child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(i));
```

So while i equals 0,1,3...14 while the loop runs, when your button is eventually clicked the loop has long since finished and i equals 15.

An easy fix to the problem is to create another variable that will hold the current value of i.

```
for (int i = 0; i < questionList.Count; i++)
{
    int questionIndex = i;
    GameObject child = Instantiate(questionButton, buttonLayout.transform);
    child.GetComponent<Text>().text = questionList[questionIndex].answer;
    child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(questionIndex));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Argument out of range means  in your case your list has 3 items, and its trying to access number 4, or 5 or anything higher than the `range` or count of your list.

also remember your list starts at 0, so your items are, 0,1, and 2

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < questionList.Count; i++)
{
    GameObject child = Instantiate(questionButton, buttonLayout.transform);
    child.GetComponent<Text>().text = questionList[i].answer;
    child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(i));
}
```

try

```
foreach(GameManager.Question q in questions){
    GameObject child = Instantiate(questionButton, buttonLayout.transform);
        child.GetComponent<Text>().text = q.answer;
        child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(i));
}
```

Comment: How about the `i`?

Comment: i can clarify. this is a for each, so basically its saying for each Question we will call q in questions do this...   so the q, is your `i` its basically saying do this to each one, one at a time and just once.  so where it says `q.answer` is equivalent to `questionList[i].answer;`

Comment: in that it will give you each answer in the list exactly one time.

Comment: I meant in `child.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => QuestionCheck(i));`, there is an undeclared `i` in `QuestionCheck(i))`, inside the `foreach`.

Comment: Use q.index or questions.indexof(q) this will give u ints int value to pass to that method